# What's the next number in sequence

Tags: cipher, pattern, number-sequence

I have been given these numbers. They are a sequence which changes every 6 months:

> 1st October 2014, number was **287669**,
>   1st April 2015, number was **323442**,
>    1st October 2015, number was **695273**.

Can you work out 1st October 16.

> Clues I've been given are : use hex or binary

Answer (score 1):

**Partial answer**

Treat the six-digit codes you've been given as

> **hex codes for colours**: [287669](http://www.color-hex.com/color/287669), [323442](http://www.color-hex.com/color/323442), [695273](http://www.color-hex.com/color/695273).

Convert these into

> the **RGB codes for the same colours**: [40,118,105](http://www.color-hex.com/color/287669); [50,52,66](http://www.color-hex.com/color/287669); [105,82,115](http://www.color-hex.com/color/695273).

Then rewrite *those* numbers

> in **binary form**: 00101000,01110110,01101001; 00110010,00110100,01000010; 01101001,01010010,01110011.

And finally, interpret *these* numbers as

> **[binary ASCII codes](http://www.ascii-code.com/)**: (vi, 24B, iRs.

What exactly these codes mean, I haven't yet figured out. But surely it's not coincidence that all these steps actually worked, and gave a relatively nice alphanumeric string at the end.

Comment: Aaah, interestinge...

Comment: @ABcDexter Interestinge, from the [Ministry of Housinge](https://youtu.be/c1RGwaCUjm0?t=215)?

Comment: I don't get it why the first three steps are necessary, why don't you just rot13(hfr n fvatyr urk-gb-ova pbairefvba vafgrnq)?

Comment: @elias Because I've no idea how those colour codes work. I just know that there's such a thing as hex colour codes, so I transformed those hex codes into colours and then took a guess at what other codes for those colours looked useful.

Comment: Why bother to convert the hex into decimal? Its actually easier to go straight from hex to binary - each hex digit becomes four binary digits. Also does look like coincidence to me but I have no better ideas...

Comment: @Chris See above comment.

Comment: The question was meant rhetorically really and the comment to be more informative. Writing on my phone and so being brief and bad at communicating due  brevity and fighting on screen keyboard)